# Woocommerce product variants on product detail page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

i'm not the experienced developer like most of you that's why i'm trying to get a little bit help from here. I'm managing a small online store from my wife and got a problem with product variants (sizes) because they're not showing up on the product detail page (https://lappya.de/produkt/der-klassiker-handtasche-mit-gesteppte-muster). I think the problem is somewhere in the template because i have the two files varations.php & variation-add-to-cart-button.php in the woocommerce folder.

My question:
1. Do you perhaps have any idea where the product variants are defined in the template?
2. Do you have any idea what code needs to be integrated to display the variants?

Thank you

Comment: Hi Dao, what template are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an explanation for your problem:

Step 1: please follow the this step http://prntscr.com/g92g2s by selecting product as variable.

Step 2: Select variation for the attribute http://prntscr.com/g92hyd

If you already did this please let me know the name of template you are using currently so I will provide more information about it.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, i exactly did these steps before but nothing happens. I use the Vendidero template (https://vendidero.de/erweiterungen/themes).

Comment: did you ask on support of https://vendidero.de/support or try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/variation-swatches-for-woocommerce/ I am also trying this one to display the product attribute. If you need more assistance please let me know